# How can I cite research material from meetings or presentations?

Tags: publications, research-process

I am writing a post-doc research paper. I want to cite research material from this meeting presentation: https://www.sitcancer.org/HigherLogic/System/DownloadDocumentFile.ashx?DocumentFileKey=0d2d7f53-3673-7aaf-3a80-518e0990e918&forceDialog=1

This meeting presentation is from the "SITC 2015 Workshop on New Perspectives for Target Antigens in the Changing Cancer Immunotherapy Landscape." Link here: https://www.sitcancer.org/communities/community-home/librarydocuments/viewdocument?DocumentKey=c4c7b592-7aae-4793-bf5a-1d136e87af3d

How should I cite material from these meetings/presentations?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the material has been published or not and in what style you want to cite.

**A general way is:** Author Surname, Initial(s) Year of publication, 'Title of paper', paper presented to Name of the conference, Place of the conference, date held. viewed Date month Year,

**So it might look something like this:** Eric T. Identification of Antigens Targeted by Tumor Infiltrating Lymphocytes to Enhance Adoptive Immunotherapy. Presented at: SITC 2015 Workshop on New Perspectives for Target Antigens in the Changing Cancer Immunotherapy Landscape Nov. 5, 2015

Now I haven't included some information, like where it took place, but you get the idea.

**Here are some guidelines for NLM, APA and Harvard style:**

- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK7255/
- http://www.easybib.com/guides/citation-guides/apa-format/conference-paper/
- http://libguides.scu.edu.au/c.php?g=356711&p=2408708

If none of these is the style you want, you can look it up now that you have an idea of what it should look like.

If you don't know in what style you should cite, you might want to ask an advisor.